# teraterm kermit stuck if connection lost

Tags: teraterm, kermit

I see that if while sending file to other device with teraterm kermit the other devise disconnect/stops receiving the file, the teraterm freeze (with kermit window opened).

I would expect there will be some timeout option but I couldn't find such. is there is such option or other ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Optional solution is to send teraterm the kermit error (E) packet which will cause teraterm to stop kermit. The packet structure can be found at https://www.kermitproject.org/kproto.pdf 4.1.

This is the right way to cause teraterm stop session if you are the other device and decided to stop receiving, but in case that the device disconnected it may also be workaround to open new connection with teraterm and send it the error pcket.